# Issue calling http request with AJax on 3 different html pages

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

```html
//home html

<body>
  <h2>Search Data from NYC Open Data Site</h2>
  <h3>Choose One Dataset Below to Start Searching</h3>

  <div>
    <label class="datasets">Data Sets:</label> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="data1" name="dataset" value="data1" required>
    <label>Data1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="data2" name="dataset" value="data2" required>
    <label>Data2</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="data3" name="dataset" value="data3" required>
    <label>Data3</label><br>
  </div><br>


  <h3 id="searchvalues"></h3>
  <br>
  <table id="searchresults"></table>
</body>
```

////1st html with search field and 2nd and 3rd as the same
`

```
<table>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td><input type="text" size="20" id="idnumber"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Year</td><td><input type="text" size="20" id="year"></td></tr>
</table>
```

`I'm doing a program with 3 different html pages to search the data using Json link. I have 3 radio buttons which will be called on change to 3 separate html pages on my home html. But when I click on radio 1 , I only get the contents of one html no matter which radio button I click, eg- when I click on 1st radio button , instead of getting data3.html, I still get the contents of data1.html and no search data is appearing. I just started learning Ajax and Json 2 weeks ago. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
var xhr;
var r;
var asynchrequest;
var radioChoices;

window.addEventListener("load", registerListeners);

function registerListeners() {

    radioChoices = document.getElementById("data1");
    radioChoices = addEventListener("change", function () { getContent("Data1.html"); }, false);
    radioChoices = document.getElementById("data2");
    radioChoices = addEventListener("change", function () { getContent("Data2.html"); }, false);
    radioChoices = document.getElementById("data3");
    radioChoices = addEventListener("change", function () { getContent("Data3.html"); }, false);
}

function getContent(infopage) {
    asynchrequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); //step 1
    asynchrequest.open("GET", infopage, true); //step 2
    asynchrequest.onreadystatechange = function () { //step 3   
        if (asynchrequest.readyState == 4 && asynchrequest.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("searchvalues").innerHTML = asynchrequest.responseText;
        }
    };
    asynchrequest.send(); //step 4
}


function loadData1() {
    //event listener
    document.getElementById("idnumber").addEventListener("keyup", function () { searchIDNumber(this.value); }, false);
    document.getElementById("year").addEventListener("keyup", function () { searchYear(this.value); }, false);
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/4d7f-74pe.json", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            r = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            //displayData(r);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}


function searchIDNumber(idnumber) {

    //var r=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    document.getElementById("searchvalues").innerHTML = "Search by ID Number" + "<br>";
    //structure table
    var output = "<tr><th> ID </th><th> Fiscal Year </th><th> Organization Name </th><th> Status </th><th> Amount </th></tr>";
    var searchid;
    for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        var obj = r[i];
        searchid = obj.mocs_id; // convert id to string from number value
        if (searchid.startsWith(idnumber)) {
            output += "<tr><td>";
            output += obj.mocs_id;
            output += "</td><td>";
            output += obj.fiscal_year;
            output += "</td><td>";
            output += obj.legal_name_of_organization;
            output += "</td><td>";
            output += obj.status;
            output += "</td><td>";
            output += obj.amount;
        }

    }
    document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML = output;
}


function searchYear(year) {

    //var r=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    document.getElementById("searchvalues").innerHTML = "Search by Year" + "<br>";
    //structure table
    var output = "<tr><th> ID </th><th> Fiscal Year </th><th> Organization Name </th><th> Status </th><th> Amount </th></tr>";
    var searchid;
    for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        var obj = r[i];
        searchid = obj.fiscal_year; // convert id to string from number value
        if (searchid.startsWith(year)) {
            output += "<tr><td>";
            output += obj.mocs_id;
            output += "</td><td>";
            output += obj.fiscal_year;
            output += "</td><td>";
            output += obj.legal_name_of_organization;
            output += "</td><td>";
            output += obj.status;
            output += "</td><td>";
            output += obj.amount;
        }

    }
    document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML = output;
    }
```

Comment: `radioChoices = addEventListener(...)` is wrong, that should be `radioChoices.addEventListener(...)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can get the search boxes shows up, but how can I call functions to call search data from json weblink? so If I choose data1 radio ad  search ID , I should have the data display but none shows up.

Comment: You will either need to bind event handlers to the relevant input fields explicitly, every time _after_ you inserted the loaded content with `document.getElementById("searchvalues").innerHTML = ...` - or use _event delegation_, to set the event listeners up once on an ancestor element that stays unchanged.

Comment: I couldn't make it work :(